# How to automate sql file execution?

Tags: oracle, plsql, automation

We have CICD in place from long time for our application. Now, we are planning to automate DB script execution as well.
PFB the requirement.

For example, we have create_tables.sql and alter_tables.sql files.

create_tables.sql contains:

```
  CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS (
  EMP_ID     VARCHAR2(128 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  FIRSTNAME    VARCHAR2(128 CHAR),
  LASTNAME    VARCHAR2(128 CHAR),
  CONSTRAINT REQUESTSUBMITTERS_PK PRIMARY KEY ( EMP_ID )
);
```

alter_tables.sql contains:

```
--v0.1
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS MODIFY FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(256);
COMMIT;

--v0.2
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS MODIFY FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(256) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS MODIFY LASTNAME VARCHAR2(256) NOT NULL;
COMMIT;

--v0.3
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS ADD EMAIL VARCHAR2(256) NOT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Assume that we have an environments ABC. This environment has all changes available in create_tables.sql file but only --v0.1 change from alter_tables.sql file.
Now, we just want to promote **JUST** --v0.2 change from alter_tables.sql file to this environment. Please note that we don't want to promote changes --v0.1 and --v0.3 from alter_tables.sql file.
So, in general there will be --v0.xxx (a unique incremental indicator) in each sql file to specify which sql statements to execute.

Can you please let me know what could be the way to automate with this approach.
Also, please feel free to suggest any other solution which you think is better than above one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `ALTER` is a DDL and it implicitly commits before and after executing that command, so - explicitly `COMMIT`ting is pretty much useless.

---

From my point of view, your approach is too difficult to apply as you have all the changes stored in the same file so you'd have to parse it and extract only some - desired - parts of it to be executed.

How about creating a set of **tables** that contains what to apply? Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table t_change_master
  2    (change       number constraint pk_cha primary key,
  3     change_date  date,
  4     cb_apply     number(1) default 0 not null,
  5     applied_date date
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> create table t_change_detail
  2    (id           number constraint pk_chadet primary key,
  3     change       number constraint fk_chadet_cha references t_change_master (change),
  4     command      varchar2(200),
  5     cb_ok        number(1),
  6     error        varchar2(200)
  7    );

Table created.
```

Some sample data:

```
SQL> insert into t_change_master (change, change_date, cb_apply)
  2    select 1, date '2022-06-25', 1 from dual union all
  3    select 2, date '2022-06-26', 0 from dual union all
  4    select 3, date '2022-06-28', 0 from dual;

3 rows created.
```

Note that ID = 1 and 4 contain duplicate commands:

```
SQL> insert into t_change_detail (id, change, command)
  2    select 1, 1, 'alter table test add firstname varchar2(20)' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 1, 'alter table test modify firstname varchar2(15)' from dual union all
  4    select 3, 2, 'alter table test add lastname varchar2(20)' from dual union all
  5    select 4, 2, 'alter table test add firstname varchar2(30)' from dual union all
  6    select 5, 3, 'alter table test add address varchar2(30)' from dual;

5 rows created.

SQL>
```

This is table that will be used in this playground:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.
```

Procedure that does the job; in two nested loops, it reads rows from the *master* table which are scheduled to run (`cb_apply = 1`) but have not been ran yet (`applied_date is null`). Inner loop just reads what to do, executes it and logs whether it was successful or not.

Basically, you'd **schedule** its execution using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (or `DBMS_JOB`, depending on your database version):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_change is
  2    l_err varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_m in (select change
  5                  from t_change_master
  6                  where cb_apply = 1
  7                    and applied_date is null
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      for cur_d in (select id, command
 11                    from t_change_detail
 12                    where change = cur_m.change
 13                   )
 14      loop
 15        begin
 16          dbms_output.put_line(cur_d.command);
 17          execute immediate cur_d.command;
 18
 19          update t_change_detail set
 20            cb_ok = 1
 21            where id = cur_d.id;
 22        exception
 23          when others then
 24            l_err := sqlerrm;
 25            update t_change_detail set
 26              cb_ok = 0,
 27              error = l_err
 28              where id = cur_d.id;
 29        end;
 30      end loop;
 31      update t_change_master set
 32        applied_date = sysdate
 33        where change = cur_m.change;
 34    end loop;
 35  end;
 36  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

OK, let's try it. Setting date format, just to know *what is what*:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    p_change;
  3  end;
  4  /
alter table test add firstname varchar2(20)
alter table test modify firstname varchar2(15)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t_change_master;

 CHANGE CHANGE_DATE           CB_APPLY APPLIED_DATE
------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
      1 25.06.2022 00:00:00          1 05.07.2022 17:50:01
      2 26.06.2022 00:00:00          0
      3 28.06.2022 00:00:00          0

SQL> select * from t_change_detail;

 ID  CHANGE COMMAND                                         CB_OK ERROR
--- ------- ---------------------------------------------- ------ ----------------------------------------
  1       1 alter table test add firstname varchar2(20)         1
  2       1 alter table test modify firstname varchar2(15)      1
  3       2 alter table test add lastname varchar2(20)
  4       2 alter table test add firstname varchar2(30)
  5       3 alter table test add address varchar2(30)

SQL>
```

Let's now run `change = 2`:

```
SQL> update t_change_master set cb_apply = 1 where change = 2;

1 row updated.

SQL> begin
  2    p_change;
  3  end;
  4  /
alter table test add lastname varchar2(20)
alter table test add firstname varchar2(30)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t_change_master;

 CHANGE CHANGE_DATE           CB_APPLY APPLIED_DATE
------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
      1 25.06.2022 00:00:00          1 05.07.2022 17:50:01
      2 26.06.2022 00:00:00          1 05.07.2022 17:50:58
      3 28.06.2022 00:00:00          0

SQL> select * from t_change_detail;

 ID  CHANGE COMMAND                                         CB_OK ERROR
--- ------- ---------------------------------------------- ------ ----------------------------------------
  1       1 alter table test add firstname varchar2(20)         1
  2       1 alter table test modify firstname varchar2(15)      1
  3       2 alter table test add lastname varchar2(20)          1
  4       2 alter table test add firstname varchar2(30)         0 ORA-01430: column being added already
                                                                  exists in table

  5       3 alter table test add address varchar2(30)

SQL>
```

Right; it kind of *works*.

Certainly, that piece of code (I wrote in a matter of minutes) could/should be improved, but that's just the general idea.

---

On the other hand, why wouldn't you do that using **version control system**, such as Git or Subversion? Good people developed these tools which are much, much more powerful that anything me (or you) could "invent" in such a short time. I guess it's worth to check these products.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed response. I will spend some time to see how your solution can be used in our case. Also, yes we are using GIT and we are exploring that option as well. It would be great if you share your inputs on how this can be achieved using GIT.